# CPU completely occupied by strange programs with person names

Tags: cpu, malware

[image]

Anyone knows why this happens and how to resolve it?
they show up out of nowhere and stay until I kill each manually.
some of these names change to something new too.
I thought this might be because I left the root access open so I closed it later..

Comment: **Immediately disconnect from the Internet!** Then from a known good clean system, download an appropriate malware/antivirus app and move it to the infected system via a USB drive and install from there. Then scan the system. **Keep the system off line until you're sure it's no longer infected!**

Comment: Thank you. cleaning it with Avast now :)

Comment: @JL After clean up could you incorporate an update for future readers telling how this might have happened? Not trying to sound mean after this incident but safety is the key.

Comment: Never "leave root access open". MacOS does have significant security features, but if you leave the door wide open, anything can come in.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Immediately disconnect from the Internet!**

   A possibly compromised system should not remain connected to a network or the Internet so as to stop any possible data breach! Even if a data breach has already occurred, the first step is to disconnect as a step to mitigate damages.
2. Power down the system and boot it from an external source that is outfitted with the tools to examine the infected disk and take appropriate action.
3. Run a malware scanner on your computer as malware process names are often randomised from a list. One of these should give you some indication of whether anything is wrong from a malware point of view:

   - [Malwarebytes for Mac](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mac/)
   - [Sophos for Mac](https://home.sophos.com/en-us/download-mac-anti-virus.aspx)
   - [Avast](https://www.avast.com/index#mac)

Comment: Pete, I've included the feedback from the comment into your answer and undeleted it. Flag for mod attention if you feel the answer shouldn't be associated with your account any longer.