# Weird processes hogging lots of resources on my MacBook

Tags: macos, mac, mojave

[image]

This is an old screenshot but basically these two processes (eriocaulaceae and stahlhelmer) just popped out of nowhere, and I couldn't find any information online. Just now they were hogging 99% of CPU but it disappeared when I opened stack exchange tab to post this question.

Any help identifying these two processes would be greatly appreciated.

I have mid 2012 MacBook Pro with 10.14.5 Mojaves.

Comment: Time to get the antivirus software out of retirement. Related, but no answer - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361687/cpu-completely-occupied-by-strange-programs-with-person-names

Comment: @Tetsujin There actually was an answer on the original question which unfortunately was deleted instead of amended after receiving a comment. Fixed now :-)

Comment: @nohillside - I could see it but was aware a new user wouldn't be able to. Thanks for pulling it all together in a coherent answer.

Comment: thank you@Tetsujin, I downloaded Malwarebytes but it didn't detect anything, so I downloaded avast and it turns out my device was infected with crypto miners. I was wondering why my laptop was overheating. Again, thanks a lot