# Mysterious process 'phonetism' eats CPU and vanishes

Tags: mojave, cpu, activity-monitor

My 2015 MacBook running Mojave has been acting strange lately, especially whilst browsing. Sometimes Safari will freeze up, or reload a page out of the blue. I can feel my computer struggling, so I'm quick to open Activity Monitor to try and see what's going on. Several times now, I've noticed a root process named 'phonetism' at the top, but it usually vanishes before I can read anything about it. Today, I finally managed to get a screenshot of it.

[image: Screenshot taken shortly before 'phonetism' disappears]

I can't find anything in the activity monitor about the process after it disappears, but I did check the console, where the only results are from ReportCrash, and look like this:
[image: SenderMachUUID is partially censored because I'm not sure whether it's harmless thing to put out there or not.]
However, these crash reports don't appear to have been written at times where I've noticed the CPU problems.

I've tried searching the web for anything related to this, but I'm at a complete loss. Any help or general ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check what other processes are running as root & see if there is a naming pattern of 'real but obscure words of a similar category that aren't often used in real life'. I think you may have a variant of this malware - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361687/cpu-completely-occupied-by-strange-programs-with-person-names - it's been seen using people's names, plant & animal genera, etc.

Comment: Tying these all together to try keep a track on the name variations - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/364276/harpulia-and-javanese-processes-cause-high-cpu-usage &  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362613/weird-processes-hogging-lots-of-resources-on-my-macbook

Comment: You can keep a terminal window open, ready for when you see this happening, then execute this command:  `lsof -R +c40`  and it will list all open files, including that process. The parameter -R will show if it has any parent PID who started it, so you can see the path on disk from that strange process, and also who/what other process started it, also along with its path on disk. And delete or investigate it deeper. (the parameter +c40 is to extend the first column of the listing up to 40 chars)