# "Harpulia" and "Javanese" processes cause high cpu usage

Tags: google-chrome, cpu

I'm wondering what is the purpose of "Harpulia" and "Javanese" processes (see screenshot below)

[image]Hi !

They're high in CPU usage (and make my macbook pro fans to be running loud) and they do not seem to be essential as I can cut it so the fans are slowing down.

Oftentime these processes appear when I watch a video on chrome but it is not the only time they appear.
On the other hand, they do not seem to be related to any chrome processes.

Thanks in advance for the help.

PS : on the screenshot these processes does not use much CPU compared to most of the time (it can be more than 100% per process).

Comment: Malware. Disconnect from the net immediately. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361687/cpu-completely-occupied-by-strange-programs-with-person-names Sometimes it's people's names,. sometimes plants...

Comment: Thanks a lot. You were right. Didn't think at all about a possible malware. I've been running malwarebyte anti-malware and everything is fixed now.